# Load RSS/XML feed with ember.js via google jsapi

Tags: xml, rss, ember.js, jsapi

I am trying to get an XML feed into my app via google jsapi and i get so close but just am at the head banging stage with this error.

**Uncaught Error: Cannot perform operations on a Metamorph that is not in the DOM.**

The problem is this line: `me.pushObject(t);`

How do i access the parent scope from within that function? Am I approaching this wrong, is there a entirely different way to do this?

I can confirm that I am getting the XML back, I just can't get it out of that function back to ember.

In desperation, I have tried `App.myController.pushObject(t);` and many other comical solutions.

I test with JSON and it 100% works but I have to load an XML RSS, so that's out.

Here is a snippet of the problem:

```
    App.myController = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    init: function(){
        me = this;

        function feedLoaded(result) {
            me.set('content', []);
            if (!result.error) {
                var mObj = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
                    var cData = result.feed.entries[i];
                    var t = App.HospTime.create({
                        title: cData.title,
                        name: cData.name,
                        date: cData.date
                    });
                    me.pushObject(t);
                }
            } else {
                alert(result.error);
            }
        }

        var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("myrss_feed.xml");
        feed.load(feedLoaded);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If I remove this entire function   `function feedLoaded(result) {` and replace it with a *jSON* call it works fine and passes the *jSON* data back to the controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try using jQuery.proxy() [[jQuery reference]](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) and see if that helps.

So, instead of `feed.load(feedLoaded);`, you could try setting `me` as the context (this) of `feedLoaded` using `feed.load($.proxy(feedLoaded, me));`, and do another `me = this` inside feedLoaded.

Also, wouldn't `me.set('content', []);` have problems with context too? Maybe I'm misinterpreting your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion i gave it a try but no go